# Expressões Regulares no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

'Selecione da tabelas CIDADES apenas registros com nomes compostos separados por um único espaço'

```
TABLE CIDADES

ID  CIDADE
01  SAO PAULO
02  RIO DE JANEIRO
03  SAO CARLOS
04  TAUBATÉ
05  SÃO JOSÉ DO RIO PRETO
```

A Consulta pode retornar apenas

```
TABLE CIDADES

ID  CIDADE
01  SAO PAULO
03  SAO CARLOS
```

COMO ESCREVER UMA EXPRESSÃO REGULAR QUE ME RETORNE AS CIDADES COMPOSTAS POR APENAS 2 NOMES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou assumir que fazemos essa verificação pelo número de espaços...

```
 select * from cidades 
 where regexp_count(cidade,' ')=1
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 1):

Para casos em que existe mais de um espaço, uma opção é essa:

```
SELECT * FROM CIDADES 
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(CIDADE, '[[:alpha:]]\s{1,}[[:alpha:]]') =  1;
```